# flask_jwt_extended giving "jwt.exceptions.InvalidSignatureError: Signature verification failed" error

Tags: python, jwt, amazon-cognito, flask-jwt-extended

I am using `AWS Coginto` to sign in a user and retrieve the authorization and refresh token response. I am able to successfully authenticate, retrieve the tokens, and decode the tokens. I verify the tokens are decoded on https://jwt.io/.

However, when I use the `flask_jwt_extended.set_access_cookies()` with the `access_token` returned from `Cognito` I get an error saying

```py
jwt.exceptions.InvalidSignatureError: Signature verification failed
```

The login and code setting the access token is below.

```py
import os
import boto3
from flask import Flask, request, make_response, redirect, render_template
from flask_jwt_extended import set_access_cookies

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.form['username']
        password = request.form['password']

        auth_response = boto3.client('cognito-idp').admin_initiate_auth(
            UserPoolId=os.environ['AWS_COGNITO_USER_POOL_ID'],
            ClientId=os.environ['APP_CLIENT_ID'],
            AuthFlow='ADMIN_NO_SRP_AUTH',
            AuthParameters={
                'USERNAME': username,
                'PASSWORD': password
            }
        )

        response = make_response(redirect('login_success', 302))
        set_access_cookies(response, auth_response['AccessToken'], max_age=15)

        return response

    return render_template('login.html')
```

Comment: How do you configure the `flask_jwt_extended` module? Should it have access to the public / secret key so that it can properly verify the signature? Have you checked where exactly is the error thrown? Does it come from the `set_access_cookies` method?

Comment: I have configured the JWT keys. I'll add that to the code later today. It comes from the set_access_cookies method. I've used pdb to step through and this is the exact line causing the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was the public key being set was from a previously deleted cognito pool and needed to be updated to the current one.